# Sobrepor gráficos com ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

estou aprendendo a usar o ggplot2 e gostaria de fazer um gráfico e em seguida sobrepor um ponto no mesmo. Por exemplo:

`set.seed(1)`

`a = data.frame(X1 = rnorm(3), X2 = rnorm(3))`

`g <- ggplot(a, aes(x = X1, y = X2), colour="black", fill = NA) + geom_polygon()`

`ponto = c(-.4, .5)`

Desde já agradeço!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma solução quick-and-dirty seria criar o ponto com um `data.frame`.

```
g + geom_point(data=data.frame(x=-0.4, y=0.5), aes(x=x, y=y), colour='white')
```